# Remove need of creating backup file while importing Excel spreadsheet to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio

I am new to ASP.NET and C# and I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server 2005.

I have a web application which contain a function which uploads data from a spreadsheet imported into the database.

However, my current function copies the spreadsheet uploaded into a directory, and used the uploaded file in the directory for reading of contents instead.

I would like to change it such that it will not create a backup copy of the uploaded excel file, and read the file contents directly from the uploaded file instead of the backup created.

Below is my code snippet for the import function for `.xls` and `.xlsx` spreadsheet:

```
if (FileImport.HasFile)
        {

            // Get the name of the Excel spreadsheet to upload. 
            string strFileName = Server.HtmlEncode(FileImport.FileName);

            // Get the extension of the Excel spreadsheet. 
            string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

            // Validate the file extension. 
            if (strExtension == ".xls" || strExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                    // Generate the file name to save. 
                    string strUploadFileName = "C:/Documents and Settings/user01/My Documents/Visual Studio 2005/WebSites/MajorProject/UploadFiles/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;

                    // Save the Excel spreadsheet on server. 
                    FileImport.SaveAs(strUploadFileName);

                    // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
                    string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strUploadFileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

                    using (OleDbConnection connection =
                                 new OleDbConnection(connStr))
                    {
                        string selectStmt = string.Format("Select [COLUMNS]  FROM [userlist$]");

                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectStmt, connection);

                        connection.Open();
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened");
                        // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
                        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            // SQL Server Connection String
                            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=<datasource>";

                            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
                            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                                       new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                            {
                                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserDB";
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

---

Below is my code snippet for the import function for `.csv` spreadsheet:

```
if (strExtension == ".csv")
{
        // Generate the file name to save. 
        string dir = @"C:\Documents and Settings\user01\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\MajorProject\UploadFiles\";
        string mycsv = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;
        // Save the Excel spreadsheet on server. 
        BaanImport.SaveAs(dir + mycsv);

        // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
        string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir + ";Extended Properties=Text;";
        using (OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            string selectStmt = string.Format("SELECT [COLUMNS] FROM " + mycsv);

            OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(selectStmt, ExcelConnection);

            OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);

            ExcelConnection.Open();

            using (DbDataReader dr = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // SQL Server Connection String
                string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=<datasource>";

                // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                           new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserDB";
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

---

May I know how could I change it such that it will not create a copy in the `dir:@"C:\Documents and Settings\user01\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\MajorProject\UploadFiles\`, but read the data directly from the imported file instead?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the object you are working with for the imported files is an HttpPostedFile, then you can use its InputStream to read the file directly from its uploaded location.

See [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx) for more information and sample code.